# Convert image to byte arrary in WinCE framework using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, windows-ce

I need to display Image on an external USB device using Serial Port communication. For this, I am converting image to byte array and passing this byte data via a serial port.
However, in WinCE framework, the existing conversion methods of C# are not supported. I have used below code snippet-

```
public byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
   using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
      imageIn.Save(ms,imageIn.RawFormat);
      return  ms.ToArray();
   }
}
```

Below line of code is not supported in WinCE framework-

```
imageIn.RawFormat
```

Please suggest any other function for WinCE only

Comment: Have you looked at System.Drawing.ImageConverter

Answer (score 0):

You can specify image format explicitly (if you know it):

```
imageIn.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
```